# Rails precompiled assets SCSS with LTR & RTL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sass, asset-pipeline

This one is not easy!

I'm building a page that switches between two locales AR & EN (RTL & LTR)
page is built using SCSS bootstrap v3.

having this as a fun fact:
http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.FAQ.html#q-ruby-code

I already have all Boostrap files switch between left & right based on one single SCSS flag (ie. $flag-direction)

My main concern now is what to do with assets pipeline on Production environment ? things seems to work fine when switching between RTL & LTR flag.
But in production it only creates on version and then starts serving that version. Did anyone work around this ?

I always end up finding solutions like these: http://dolinked.com/questions/229493/maintain-rtl-version-of-stylesheets-with-rails-asset-pipeline
which are a little scary since it's too much of a work around. is there anything simpler ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

As I do understand you want compile all code into a single CSS file? Unless you change the Bootstrap code yourself, i expect that you will load many unused CSS code. If your are able to set the text directory of your HTML conditionally, you should also able to load your CSS file(s) dynamically and compile a CSS file for each text direction.

Otherwise you possible can use the [nested @import](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#nested-import) feature of Sass:

With grid.scss:

```
@at-root body#{&} {
direction: $direction;
}
.row {
float: $float;
}
```

The following code:

```
.rtl {
$direction: rtl;
$float: left;
@import "grid.scss";
}


.ltr {
$direction: ltr;
$float: right;
@import "grid.scss";
}
```

compiles into CSS code as follows:

```
body.rtl {
  direction: rtl; }
.rtl .row {
  float: left; }

body.ltr {
  direction: ltr; }
.ltr .row {
  float: right; }
```

Comment: yeah, all this is doable but my question was with production deployment. Assets will be pipelined once with either LTR or RTL and get served with only one version